# Blocking a specific application's access to a specific domain

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, blocking, windows-firewall

I want to block a specific application's access to a domain. I would normally do this by adding the domain to my `hosts` file and having it redirect to localhost, but that will disable all applications' access to the domain. I wish to make this selective so only one application is prevented from accessing the domain. What steps are required to do this on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

Go to windows firewall --->  outbound rules ---> new rule ---> rule type --> then enter path of the program exe like C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe and then select the action , block the connection , choose the profiles you can select all , then give the name to your rule. After rule created right click on rule in the list and properties , select coverage or scope , set the ip addresses for the web sites you wanna block , how to learn the ip address for the web site , you can use command prompt ping command like ping www.facebook.com which will return the ip address for the site.